# Undeleted files on FTP

Tags: ftp, mirror

I have just deleted files from the my main server but they appear to be still present on the FTP server. Yet, there is a mirroring that is supposed to be done.

The purged directory is empty, yet a 'Locate' still points to the directory. Via SSH, the directory is empty and via FTP, the directory is full of files.

Can anyone help or at least point me to the right direction?

BRegards,

Comment: your FTP client might be caching the contents of your server, if you are using a GUI based ftp client. If you can ssh to the server and see the files gone, they are gone.

Comment: Hello, I have ssh-ed on the ftp server and they are still here...and via an FTP client they still appear here. But the files have already been deleted on the main server. Are symlinks an issue here?

Comment: symlinks do not matter but if someone created hard links to those files, until the last of those links gets removed, the file will stay. Having said that, did you check the file/directory permissions from the top, i.e. root directory, to see if the ftpuser has permissions to delete files and directories ?